# Cleaning SQL Data that has periods as missing values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to move data from a table with varchar columns to a table with numeric columns.  Below is an example of values in a column, where sometimes a period will be used to denote a missing value.

```
    Column1
    0.00
    4.80
     .  
     .  
    0.00
     .  
    0.00
     .
```

'Error converting data type varchar to numeric.' pops up when it reaches the periods.  How can I deal with the periods (either removing them or changing them to 0.00) so that I can continue copying the data into the new table?

For reference, here is the code I am using:

```
    INSERT INTO [CORE]
       [NumberDone]
       ,[Charges]
    SELECT
       LEFT([Column0],8)
       ,LEFT([Column1],8)
    FROM [TempTbl];
```

Comment: I hope that your new table is using a numeric datatype for this instead of varchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 2012+, Try_Convert() may help here.  Not only will Try_Convert() trap the single decimal, but any other unexpected strings.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Column1] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('0.00')
,('4.80')
,('.')
,('.')
,('0.00')
,('.')
,('0.00')
,('.')

Select Try_Convert(decimal(10,2),Column1)
 from @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
0.00
4.80
NULL
NULL
0.00
NULL
0.00
NULL
```

**NOTE**: If you'd rather Zeros, `IsNull(Try_Convert(decimal(10,2),Column1),0)`

So, for the actual Insert

```
insert into [core] ([NumberDone], [Charges])
select try_convert(decimal(10,2),Column0)
     , try_convert(decimal(10,2),Column1)
from [TempTbl];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nullif()` to turn `'.'` into `null`:

```
insert into [core] ([NumberDone], [Charges])
select 
    left(nullif([Column0], '.'), 8)
  , left(nullif([Column1], '.'), 8)
from [TempTbl];
```

---

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DIVNJ65404

```
create table TempTbl ([Column1] varchar(50));
insert into TempTbl values 
 ('0.00'),('4.80'),('.'),('.')
,('0.00'),('.'),('0.00'),('.');

select Column1 = left(nullif([Column1], '.'), 8)
from [TempTbl];
```

returns:

```
+---------+
| Column1 |
+---------+
| 0.00    |
| 4.80    |
| NULL    |
| NULL    |
| 0.00    |
| NULL    |
| 0.00    |
| NULL    |
+---------+
```

---

You could wrap that in `isnull()` or `coalesce()` to turn `null` into `0`.

```
insert into [core] ([NumberDone], [Charges])
select 
    isnull(left(nullif([Column0], '.'), 8),0)
  , isnull(left(nullif([Column1], '.'), 8),0)
from [TempTbl];
```

Comment: I did up vote your answer but as OP says that '.' denotes a "missing value" then... it's probably a good idea to leave it as NULL and not to turn NULL into zero.

Comment: @mauro I agree, but I added the second option because of this part of the question: "(either removing them or changing them to 0.00)"

Comment: For whatever reason I couldn't get nullif() to work, but thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
case when charges='.' then 0 else cast(charges as double precision) end
```